# Rails 3 I/O to and From background process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, io

**Short version:** I need to launch a subprocess (a Ruby script) from a Rails controller (using Rails 3), and render `stdout` messages from the subprocess to a webpage, and pass information into the subprocess from a Rails view.

**The Setup:** I have a Ruby script that communicates with a software messaging bus system called [Ivy](http://www.tls.cena.fr/products/ivy/), using Ruby 1.9.3 to send control messages to and receive messages from some hardware running elsewhere on my network. I cannot use an alternative messaging system here, it must be Ivy. The script currently writes messages to `stdout`.

**Problem 1:** I would like to launch this script as a subprocess (or thread, I'm open to suggestions) from the controller of a Rails app. I would like to be able to receive messages from this script such that they can be displayed on a webpage. There is no need to store these messages persistently in a database, so I was considering using the Rails cache to store and access the messages temporarily and perhaps poll the cache for new messages on an interval using AJAX. Is this possible?

**Problem 2:** That same Rails app needs to be able to send control messages from a web page (e.g., through a user interacting with buttons, drop downs or some other UI elements) to the Ivy subprocess such that these control messages can propagate to the hardware.

I have looked into potential solutions like [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/), [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), and others, but I cannot find conclusive evidence through browsing docs that these potential solutions can solve both Problem 1 and 2. So, my questions are as follows:

1. Can a ready-made solution like Sidekiq or DelayedJob handle this task?
2. Is there some way built into Rails already that I can accomplish this?
3. This question borders on opinion, but I'll ask it anyways. I have other reasons for pursuing Rails, but they may be trumped if this task is going to be extremely difficult. Is doing something like this using Rails such a pain that I should look into alternative solutions?

Comment: rails 4 supports live streaming ([check this](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there are 3 concerns:

1. Monitoring the ivybus for messages
2. Sending commands over the ivybus
3. User Interaction (web interface)

The Rails framework is only solving concern number 3. That's all it's designed to do. However, that doesn't mean that Ruby / Rails is not a great tool for this job. Here are some thoughts I have on setting this up:

Concern 1 should definitely be happening within some kind of background job. It should not be part of the standard web request. I would argue that concern 2 would also work better in a background job. Any error-prone or potentially long running tasks should really be kept out of web requests when possible.

There are several ways to get these tasks things into the background. Sidekiq is a perfect solution for concern 2 (sending commands). The controller will receive a request from the user to do some action, and the controller submits a job to the background worker to do it. Sidekiq can also solve concern 1 (monitoring), but you would have to create periodic jobs (like polling) to continue to check the interface for new messages. Sidekiq is not meant to run jobs that will run indefinitely.

The most robust way to solve concern 1 is to create a daemon. It may seem overkill, but gems like "daemons" make this a pretty easy task. This daemon could monitor the interface and push data you care about into some kind of datastore (MySQL, Redis, etc.).

You can use either one or both of these backgrounding solutions and solve this problem, but I definitely think you need a separate process to manage at least the 1st concern. This would allow concern 3 (your web application) to only deal with reading data from a datastore and rendering it for the user, and turning certain requests (commands) into background jobs. That keeps your Rails app doing what it does best, but still lets you do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is (mostly) fine.

Sidekiq, or Resque, would be a good way to do the Ivy polling.  You can schedule a worker to periodically poll the for new messages.

While Rails 4 does live streaming, it's not quite ready for prime time.  I'd suggest using something like a Node.js/Socket.io setup to talk to the client browser over WebSockets.  Or, if fancy realtime updates aren't a requirement and clients will be small in number, just have the workers dump the results in a DB and have the browser poll for updates.

But, the Ivy is the sticky point.  I don't see much out there about talking to Ivy from a Ruby/Rails app.  Perhaps you could use JRUby and then use one of the Java wrappers.

Since you aren't super married to Rails, it'd probably be easier to do this in Python or Perl since the Ivy people have tools written in those languages already.